# Node. js server process with web change

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
app.post('/upload',upload.array('photos',30),function(req,res,next){
    for (var index in req.files)
        {    
        var file = req.files[index];
        var loc = file.destination;
        var output= uploadFolder+req.body.user+'/download/'+formatDate();
        };
    console.log('output: '+output);
    console.log('loc: '+loc);
    var cmd = 'python demo.py -i '+loc+' -o '+output+' --isDlib True'; //cmd demo.py 
    // res.write('File Processing..');

    child_process.exec(cmd,function(err,stdout,stderr){            
        var fileLocation = output+'.zip';
        console.log(fileLocation);

        zipFolder(output,fileLocation, function(err) {

            if(err) {
                console.log('oh no!', err);
            } else {

                console.log('EXCELLENT');
                res.download(fileLocation,'Files');                    
                // res.redirect('/form');                  
            }
        });                 
   }); 
});
```

Hi everyone, I've just started out with Node and I tried to build a simple server  to let user upload their image. The image will then be changed to 3D by python.

Now I want to display a message when the user is waiting for the file transfer to complete.

I tried to send the message by response.write  before the child_process ,and in the end I wish to redirect the website by route.

But I always get the error （The codes which I comment out. ）:
`Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Can someone help me to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you update your question by copying your code into the question and format it accordingly using the tools provided.

Comment: @slee423 I already fixed it. Thank You so mush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that once you call `res.send` your API's response will be returned (on line 74).

Hence you get the error `Can't set headers after they are sent` because the res object has already been returned by node.

Calling `res.redirect` on line 88 has the same effect as well.

You cannot send a response back when the file is being uploaded. Sending a response will finish your API call. And you will have to make a separate call to check the status of your upload. I would recommend showing a response that your file is being uploaded, from the frontend instead of the API.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) would be helpful in getting a better understanding of how res works!

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for your answer. 
But if I wanna show some message on client , just in one response. 
It's that possible ? 
Like use  'next()' to make process?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, next() is usually used with middleware. So I dont think you can use that to display messages on the client.

Comment: Instead, you could get your frontend web or mobile application to display a message while waiting for the API to respond.

Answer (score 3):

As Sashi said correctly, you can't respond twice from your API

Try:

someUploadRoute.js:

```
...
..
console.log(fileLocation);
zipFolder(output,fileLocation, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    myMessage="error encountered on upload"
    console.log(myMessage, err);
    res.json({success:false, error:err});
  }
  else {
    myMessage = "upload successful";
    console.log(myMessage);
    res.download(fileLocation, 'Files');
  }
)}
```

**Edit** to display message to frontend:

When your someUploadComponent.ts calls your someUploadService.service.ts you could check for the returned values. Partially pseudo code follows:

someUploadComponent.ts:

```
   this.someUploadService.upload(args).subscribe(uploadResponse => {
     if (uploadResponse.success == false) { // will be undefined if no err
       display err message in dialog or whateva
     }
     else {
       do whatever..
     }
```

someUploadService.service.ts:

```
upload(args) {
   return this.http.post('http://somehost:3000/fileOps/upload',user).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
But I want to show the message on client,not on terminal.
It's that possible I sent some message  in just one response?

Comment: check for the returned json for success.false in your component and display a dialog, snackbar, div (set visibility) or whatever..